# if(!isset($_POST["user"]) ignored and returns Undefined Index

Tags: php, post, isset

When I output this code,

```
23  if(!isset($_POST['user'])) {
24    $user = $_POST['user'];
25    $user2 = $user;
26    $pass[0] = $_POST['password'];
27    $pass[1] = $_POST['password2'];
28    $email[0] = $_POST['email'];
29    $email[1] = $_POST['email2'];
30    $agree = $_POST['agreed'];
31    $reprint['user'] = $user;
32    $reprint['password'] = $pass[0];
33    $reprint['email'] = $email[0];
34    $reprint['agree'] = $agree;
```

it returns

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Arena\create_account.inc on line 24
Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Arena\create_account.inc on line 26
Notice: Undefined index: password2 in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Arena\create_account.inc on line 27
Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Arena\create_account.inc on line 28
Notice: Undefined index: email2 in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\Arena\create_account.inc on line 29
```

Note that there is no error for line 23, so isset() always returns true; I don't get any error when all my $_POST[] are actually set. You might not be able to reproduce this; it may be only EasyPHP. I'm on the latest EasyPHP right now, with PHP 5.3.6 VC9. I've always had this problem with all versions of EasyPHP... So I'm not sure if there is a "better" syntax or a way to prevent EasyPHP from displaying these errors.

Answer (score 7):

You are saying if `$_POST['user']` has *not* been set. Try removing the negation operator `!`.

```
// if user key has *not* been set
if(!isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user']; // undefined index because there is no 'user' key


if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user']; // no problems here
```

Comment: @Xifanie - It's all good. You were stuck for a silly reason. Happens to everyone, every day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
```

The !isset means if it is not set.

Answer (score 0):

isset() returns true if a variable is set and false if it is not. THe current logic only executes if $_POST['user'] is NOT set. Is this intentional?

It seems to me you need to remove your not operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

:)

I think you should change `isset` to `!empty`...

```
!empty($_POST["user"])
```